# Make a picklist mandatory when value is selected on another picklist

Tags: validation, dependent-picklist

I want to Make a picklist called "Reason" to be mandatory when the value on another picklist called "Status" equals to decline.How can this be achieved using validations?

Comment: There are various way you can achieve this through Validation rule,  JavaScript on VF Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use validation rule to achieve this. Assuming `Status` and `Reason` both are custom fields, the below formula should work for you.

```
AND(
TEXT( Status__c ) = "decline",
ISBLANK(TEXT( Reason__c)))
```